# Error updating Multiple records with SQL subquery error

Tags: sql-server, subquery

I come from a C# linq background so im trying to learn SQL.
I would like a simple subquery that will update multiple records in my [AccountContact] table with new UserID's that correspond to the ContactID in the [User] Table.
i do not want to use joins.

My code is as follows

```
UPDATE [dbo].[AccountContact]
 SET UserID = (SELECT UserID from [User] WHERE ContactID IS NOT NULL),
     ContactID = null 
GO
```

Thanks in Advance
By running this code i get the error

`Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.`

Comment: your `(SELECT UserID from [User] WHERE ContactID IS NOT NULL)` returns more than one value and you only need one. How is the new userid determined?

Comment: Can you provide some sample data and desired results?

Comment: I know it returns more than 1 value, it needs to update thousands of userID's in the AccountContact table.

 @ Nadeem your query does exactly what mine does just a longer version of it :) 

pretty much what i need is to update my AccountContacts table. 

In my [User] table i have 2 columns UserID and ContactID. 
In my [AccountContact] table i have 2 columns UserID and ContactID.

This query is supposed to set all UserID's in the [AccountContact] table to the corrosponding ContactID from the [User] table.

But because i am returning just over 3000 rows records i get the error stated above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution to this problem

I have edited my code as follows

```
UPDATE [AccountContact]
    SET UserID = ISNULL((SELECT UserID FROM [User] WHERE [User].[ContactID] = [AccountContact].[ContactID]),[AccountContact].UserID),
    ContactID = NULL
    WHERE [AccountContact].[ContactID] IS NOT NULL
```

This does exactly what i need it to.

Answer (score 0):

I think you require this

```
UPDATE [dbo].[AccountContact] SET UserID = 'Whatever value you want',
ContactID = null where UserID = (SELECT UserID from [User] WHERE ContactID IS NOT NULL)
```

Answer (score 0):

Find attached links to the images

---

[Initail Tables](http://postimg.org/image/wjxckmibj/)

What I need done is to update my AccountContact table where the userID is null,

what needs to happen is in the account contact table you see the first record has no UserID only a ContactID.

ContactID 28 will have a UserID of 3 as shown by the [User] table.

Now AccountContact table needs to have all records updated where UserID  = Null .

Then once all the UserID has been updated in the AccountContact Table the ContactID’s must be set to null.

**After my Query has ran the AccountContact table should be as follows**

[Query Complete](http://postimg.org/image/61p1g9a03/)

Its just updating all the UserID's in the [AccountContact] with the correct corresponding UserID from the [User] where it has a ContactID